# Trouble aligning ggplot maps due to different sign in longitude

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, latitude-longitude, r-sf

I have a ggplot map using longitude and latitude data from one data source, and I have a map from another data source. If I call each of them individually, I get two maps that should overlap, except one of them has a negative sign for longitude, and the other has a positive sign.

```
citymap <- read_sf("~/Documents/Assessment and Taxation Revenue Analysis/lcsd000b21a_e/lcsd000b21a_e.shp")

yegmap <- citymap %>% filter(grepl('Edmonton', CSDNAME))
map <- ggplot(yegmap) + geom_sf()
map
```

Which produces this map:

[image]

Note it presents latitude and longitude as positive numbers, and labels them degrees North degrees West.

I also draw from an open data source and produce the following ggplot

```
AssessmentData <- read.socrata("https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/q7d6-ambg.csv")

AssessmentData <- mutate(AssessmentData, MillRate1 = case_when(mill_class_1 == 'RESIDENTIAL' ~ 0.0067,
                                                               mill_class_1 == 'OTHER RESIDENTIAL' ~ 0.0077,
                                                               mill_class_1 == 'COMMERCIAL' ~ .0199,
                                                               mill_class_1 == 'FARMLAND' ~0.0067 ))

AssessmentData <- mutate(AssessmentData, MillRate2 = case_when(mill_class_2 == 'RESIDENTIAL' ~ 0.0067,
                                                               mill_class_2 == 'OTHER RESIDENTIAL' ~ 0.0077,
                                                               mill_class_2 == 'COMMERCIAL' ~ .0199,
                                                               mill_class_2 == 'FARMLAND' ~0.0067 ))

AssessmentData <- mutate(AssessmentData, MillRate3 = case_when(mill_class_3 == 'RESIDENTIAL' ~ 0.0067,
                                                               mill_class_3 == 'OTHER RESIDENTIAL' ~ 0.0077,
                                                               mill_class_3 == 'COMMERCIAL' ~ .0199,
                                                               mill_class_3 == 'FARMLAND' ~0.0067 ))

AssessmentData <- AssessmentData %>% mutate(TaxGenerated1 = as.numeric(AssessmentData$assessed_value) * as.numeric(AssessmentData$tax_class_pct_1/100) * MillRate1)
AssessmentData <- AssessmentData %>% mutate(TaxGenerated2 = as.numeric(AssessmentData$assessed_value) * as.numeric(AssessmentData$tax_class_pct_2/100) * MillRate2)
AssessmentData <- AssessmentData %>% mutate(TaxGenerated3 = as.numeric(AssessmentData$assessed_value) * as.numeric(AssessmentData$tax_class_pct_3/100) * MillRate3)

AssessmentData <- AssessmentData %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(TaxGenerated = sum(TaxGenerated1, TaxGenerated2, TaxGenerated3, na.rm = TRUE))


newplot2 <- ggplot(AssessmentData, aes(longitude, latitude, z = TaxGenerated), crs <-(4269)) + 
  stat_summary_2d(bins = 200, fun = function(z) sum(z)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "brown", high = "yellow")

plot(newplot2)
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

You will notice the difference in signs between the two maps. One reads -113.7 for longitude, the other reads 113.7W. Obviously both should be -113.7, since we're in the Western hemisphere. Instead, it seems like I have a W attached to the longitude?

I would like to layer these two outputs so that the borders of this area are visible on the map with the 2d bin plot.

```
newplot2 <- ggplot()  + 
  stat_summary_2d(AssessmentData, mapping = aes(longitude, latitude, z = TaxGenerated), bins = 500, fun = function(z) sum(z)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "brown", high = "yellow") +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(), data = yegmap, position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE) +
  xlim(4795581, 4833535) + 
  ylim(2146663, 2184642)

plot(newplot2)
```

This generates the warning message "Removed 410407 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_summary2d()`). "

There are 410407 rows in AssessmentData, so every row is being removed. If I remove xlim and ylim from the command, I get the following plot:

[image]

I would be grateful for advice on how to reconcile these two maps.

I have tried aligning setting each to have CRS <- st_crs(4269), which is the output from st_crs(map), but seem to get an error, and I may misunderstand how to set crs.

I have tried to use the absolute values for longitude, but that appears to flip the axis, which of course is a problem, and even still all the rows in AssessmentData are dropped.

Comment: (1) It's a little hard parsing through all of that code, most of it seems unlikely to be related to the fact that `geom_sf` is giving you the `W` longitude attribute and normal ggplot2 plot is not, can you reduce it to just some data with no unrelated processing? (2) (Almost) "Never" use `$` on a frame in a magrittr pipe based on that frame. Remove `AssessmentData$` in all your pipes that start with `AssessmentData %>% ...`. (3) `crs <-(4269)` inside `ggplot(.)` is not going to do what you think, perhaps `crs=-6269`? `<-` inside a function never (by itself) is interpreted as an arg name.

Comment: (4) Have you tried something like `map + stat_summary_2d(bins = 200, fun = sum, data = AssessmentData, mapping = aes(longitude, latitude, z = TaxGenerated))`, that is, adding the new stat to the pre-defined `map` with its axes already defined?

Comment: Thanks for offering these suggestions! map + stat_summary... produced the same result as the 3rd picture (huge long/lat range with border in the top right). 

This is the first time I've tried to layer two plots with long/lat coordinates and I understand that I need to align my CRS attributes, but both seem to read as null?

I'm not having issues with the TaxGenerated variable I created with those AssessmentData$ commands, is it likely this is causing my error? They're just used to create a continuous variable which seems to be calculated ok?

Comment: Why are you setting your `xlim(4795581, 4833535)`? What happens when you don't include that? (Same for `ylim(.)`.)

Comment: Using st_bbox(yegmap) I received the output for those xlim and ylim numbers. If I remove them the 3rd photo I shared appears.

This is different from the output I received if I use st_as_sf(AssessmentData, coords = c('longitude', 'latitutde')), which gives me xmin = -113.69, ymin = 53.37, xmax -113.36, and ymax = 53.64.

Comment: I think that I may have resolved the issue (perhaps thanks to your suggestions). By introducing the following line:

yegmap <- st_transform(yegmap, coords = 'geometry', crs = 4269) before map <- ggplot(yegmap) + geom_sf()

yegmap <- st_transform(yegmap, coords = 'geometry', crs = 4269)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).